# Colorbox plugin borderless view

Tags: jquery-plugins, colorbox

I need use a modal plugin and colorbox looks great.

How do I load it w/o the rounded borders?

Given my page size, the thick border taking too much space.

Anyway to hide it or make it thinner and hide the border if needed on some calls?

Comment: Delete the border entries in the .css file.
With some trial and error it will be possible.

Comment: Katti is right, just make the changes you want through the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the borders in easy way:

```
 $("#cboxTopLeft").hide();
            $("#cboxTopRight").hide();
            $("#cboxBottomLeft").hide();
            $("#cboxBottomRight").hide();
            $("#cboxMiddleLeft").hide();
            $("#cboxMiddleRight").hide();
            $("#cboxTopCenter").hide();
            $("#cboxBottomCenter").hide();
```

and add class with border style if you want with this way :

```
.thin_border {
    border: 10px solid blue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px blue;
}
```

and then add it with jquery

```
$("#cboxContent").addClass("thin_border");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think colorbox isn't actually using the property "border" to get that huge black border going around. It seems like its being incased in a 3 x 3 div which uses images to create that border. Im sure you could remove it but its going to require messing with the actual colorbox javascript. You could try messing with the CSS as well.

You consider looking into a diffrent plugin like lightbox2 or shadowbox?  I personally use slimbox (nice little clone of lightbox).  If you want to mess with the code go for it.  Otherwise I would just pick a diffrent plugin.